# Convert Oracle to_date('24-03-20','DD-MM-RR') to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need your small help. I have to use to_date('24-03-20','DD-MM-RR') Oracle function in snowflake. Both output should be matching. Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful with YY, as RR in Oracle behaved differently than Snowflake's YY.  RR in Oracle basically made two digit years into a "closest to the year 2000" model, e.g. RR string of 49 gave you 2049, RR string of 51 gave you 1951.

If you need RR "functionality", see the reference to the TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START session parameter at this link:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions

That parameter is further defined here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-two-digit-century-start

So, you could use YY, but you'll need to run an ALTER SESSION command before you execute your select, examples as follows:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START = 1970; --the default
SELECT to_date('24-03-20', 'DD-MM-YY');           --2020-03-24

ALTER SESSION SET TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START = 1900; --not what you want
SELECT to_date('24-03-20', 'DD-MM-YY');           --1920-03-24


ALTER SESSION SET TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START = 1950; --RR like
SELECT to_date('24-03-20', 'DD-MM-YY');           --2020-03-24
SELECT to_date('24-03-49', 'DD-MM-YY');           --2049-03-24
SELECT to_date('24-03-50', 'DD-MM-YY');           --1950-03-24
```

I hope this helps...Rich